# fancybox error - Object #<Object> has no method 'undelegate'

Tags: jquery, fancybox, undelete

Been at this for over an hour now - lightbox plugin was working just fine (as expected) but for whatever reason I cannot get this fancybox plugin to work properly.

**The setup:**

> For testing purposes I am using the images from fancy box's website -
>   absolute path reference -, the jQuery declaration from their site, and
>   the css file they recommend I use.

**The error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'undelegate'

To see the error:

1. Go to [The Error Page](http://nanisolutions.us/?page_id=49) and inspect element in chrome
2. Feel free to view the source of my website, I'm almost positive I've referenced everything correctly

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi You are using older version of jQuery i.e. 1.4.1.

.undelegate() method is added in jQuery version 1.4.2. Change the jQuery version to 1.4.2 or latest and fancybox will work fine

Refrence : [Jquery .undelegate()](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/)